# Ip of terminated instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking at cloud trail logs , I could only see the instance id of the terminated instances. I have a requirement of fetching the ip(not instance id) that was assigned to a machine which has got terminated. I need this information for the machines those got terminated in last 1 hour. Is there a way I can get that by making API calls?

Comment: Question is not clear. You want the IP of a terminated instance by using its name instead of its instance id? When was instance terminated?

Comment: Hi , HelloV , I edited my question , please have a look.

Comment: I haven't tried this. You can get all events tagged with the terminated instance id. If you see RunInstances for that instance id, it will have all attributes including the ip for that instance.

Comment: The CloudTrail API name is LookupEvents. Specify the LookupAttributes and EndTime.

Comment: I'd suggest you should make the instances report the IP somewhere while they're shutting down.

Comment: You could call [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) and ask it for the IP Address based on the InstanceID. A little indirect, but at least the information would be available (assuming you've got Config turned on prior to termination).

Answer (score 2):

Using CloudTrail, I was able to search for `ResourceName = i-0123abc` and find the `RunInstances` event that had the ip in the event map under the following key tree:
`responseElements.instancesSet.items[0].privateIpAddress`